# Proof that $f(t) \leq \epsilon + f(t)^2 \Rightarrow f(t) \leq 2\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(t) \leq \epsilon +f(t)^2 \ \forall t, \epsilon>0$.  Prove that there exists $\epsilon_0 >0$ such that if $\epsilon \leq \epsilon_0$, then $f(t)\leq 2\epsilon \ \forall t$.

So far, I have set up a set $E = \{t \in [0, \infty) : f(t) \leq 2\epsilon\}$, and I believe I need to show that E is both open and closed, and use a connectedness argument.  I'm not sure how to go about this, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Let f(t) = 1 if t in [0,1], = t otherwise.
f satisfies the hypothesis.
As f is unbounded, it shows the proposition is false.